# how to validate the first four character in string using php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to make script that only accept the ff;

- 1st, 2nd, and 3rd character from a word/string/paragraph == ABC;
- 4th
  character from a word/string/paragraph == asterisk(*);
- 5th to 20th from accept only a numeric integer...

```
<?php

    $subject = "das*3445465656343";
    $pattern = '/^[ABCabc]{3}$/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

?>
```

Comment: And what is the problem now?

Comment: So the string must be 20 characters long?

Comment: i dont know how to do the validation sir,,

Comment: @chris - 20 char long sir

Comment: Here's the regex and usage. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63d5cc1ae37b25633242a7af2ad058608cbaefe4

Comment: @Bee So do we make any progress with this question ?

Comment: @Rizier123 - all are working sir... except :i want to accept only *(abc) not bca,or acb,cab,cba,,,,,

Comment: @Bee My regex only accepts abc case-insensitive, did you saw the demo?

Comment: @Rizier123 - i see the demo sir... thanks.... it accept lower or uppercase... but it also accept the rumble abc sir.... i want only to accept is abc...

Comment: @Bee No it doesn't see: https://regex101.com/r/wW9qY4/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use this regex:

```
$pattern = "/^abc\*\d{16}$/i";
```

Explanation:

- **^** assert position at start of a line
- **abc** matches the characters abc literally (case insensitive)
- **\*** matches the character * literally
- **\d{16}** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: {16} Exactly 16 times
- **$** assert position at end of a line
- **i** modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/wW9qY4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check this regex: `(?=^abc\*\d{16}$).+`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wH9xY6/5)

Comment: can you please use ur regex in the code above then return a boolean type if it is true or false....

Comment: It must start with `abc`, not `a`, `b`, or `c`, and must be 20 characters long. @Bee answer below should work, use it with `preg_match`.

Comment: thanks sir... but the first three letter accept even "abc" is rumbled;

Comment: Going by the OPs regex, `'/^[ABCabc]{3}$/' ` it's clear he wants `a b c` case insensitive in any order.

Comment: @Maus - i want to accept only *(abc) not bca,or acb,cab,cba,,,,,

Comment: OP wrote a regex that doesn't match their text description so it shouldnt be used/considered. `1st, 2nd, and 3rd character from a word/string/paragraph == ABC`

Comment: You have a few extra things here and are case sensitive. This also is becoming the same regex as the answer below which should work for the OP.

Comment: @chris85 Actually I've used an `i` flag in the demo to make it case insensitive. I agree we have similar solutions, but I just wanted the OP to know that it can be done using lookaheads. In my opinion, it's always better to check if a string matches all the prerequisite conditions before beginning a match. And I expect the OP to accept the other answer as the solution, I just want him to understand regexes better. :)